# .Net Regex - omitting space in group capture

Tags: regex

I've got something like this

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<div class="form-group">
 <label class="control-label col-md-3">Expires at:</label>
<div class="col-md-9">
<p class="form-control-static">
March 3rd, 2019 </p>
</div>
```

I wanna capture the date. The only way i know how to do it is like this which captures the space after 2019 which i don't need.

```
(?<=>Expires at:<\/label>\n<div class=\"col-md-9\">\n<p class=\"form-control-static\">\n)([^<]*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your match condition is "all characters except `<`", which is literally what you get. You can either use some kind of trimming function in your language outside of the regex to post-process it, or write the regex you actually mean:

`(?<=>Expires at:<\/label>\n<div class=\"col-md-9\">\n<p class=\"form-control-static\">\n)([ \w,]*?)\s*<`

ie, all alphanumerical characters, numbers and commas, as few as possible, followed by as many spaces as possible (or 0), followed by `<`, and only capture the first part. [See it in action here.](https://regex101.com/r/QYti7x/1)

Also, [obligatory reference to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/108796).